# Extract non zero rows from porterrshow command

Tags: linux, powershell

I am executing **"porterrshow"** command on switches using below code

```
$cred = Get-Credential

$SAN_S = @(Get-Content -Path "E:\switches.txt")

foreach($SANs in $SAN_S)
{
$session = New-SSHSession -ComputerName $SANs -Credential $cred
$Strem = New-SSHShellStream -SSHSession $Session
sleep -Seconds 10
        $SystemView = $Strem.WriteLine("porterrshow")
        $streamOut = $Strem.read() 
        $streamOut | Out-File -FilePath "E:\$SANs.txt" -Force
         
}
```

below is the output I am getting

```
          frames      enc    crc    crc    too    too    bad    enc   disc   link   loss   loss   frjt   fbsy  c3timeout    pcs    uncor
       tx     rx      in    err    g_eof  shrt   long   eof     out   c3    fail    sync   sig                  tx    rx     err    err
  0:    0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
  1:    2.5g   3.6g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      2      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0   
  2:    0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
  3:    3.3g   1.5g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      3      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0
```

I want to extract the rows which are having any value which is not **"0"**. in above line 2 and 4.

Please let me know how to do that

and I am executing this on multiple switches, so is it possible to put some filter in the **porterrshow** command itself which will show only the non-zero rows?

Output based on @Theo code

```
          frames      enc    crc    crc    too    too    bad    enc   disc   link   loss   loss   frjt   fbsy  c3timeout    pcs    uncor
       tx     rx      in    err    g_eof  shrt   long   eof     out   c3    fail    sync   sig                  tx    rx     err    err
  2:  615.8m   1.8g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      2      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0   
  3:    2.1g   1.2g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      2      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0   
  4:    1.4g   2.9g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      6      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
  5:  258.0m 623.6m   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
  6:    1.7g   1.1g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
  7:  512.5m  73.1m   0      0      0      0      0      0      0     17      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
  8:   49.6m   2.4g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
```

One of the output file for reference

```
          frames      enc    crc    crc    too    too    bad    enc   disc   link   loss   loss   frjt   fbsy  c3timeout    pcs    uncor
       tx     rx      in    err    g_eof  shrt   long   eof     out   c3    fail    sync   sig                  tx    rx     err    err
  2:  615.8m   1.8g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      2      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0   
  3:    2.1g   1.2g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      2      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0   
  4:    1.4g   2.9g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      6      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
  5:  258.0m 623.6m   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
  6:    1.7g   1.1g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
  7:  512.5m  73.1m   0      0      0      0      0      0      0     17      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
  8:   49.6m   2.4g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
  9:  599.8m   1.7g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      6      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 10:    2.8g 254.9m   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      6      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 11:  161.3m   2.8g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 12:    2.5g 556.1m   0      0      0      0      0      0      0    384      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 13:    2.9g   3.5g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      2      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 14:    1.7g   3.6g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0     12      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 15:  390.8m 980.2m   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 16:  777.7m   3.1g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      6      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 17:    1.1g   2.6g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 18:  155.7m 601.9m   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 19:    2.9g   2.8g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 20:  490.4m   4.2g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 21:    2.2g   1.0g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 22:    3.2g   3.5g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 23:    4.0g   2.9g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0     83      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 24:  167.2m   1.0g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 25:    1.2g   2.3g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      5      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 26:    2.1g 647.2m   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 27:   81.7m 294.3m   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 28:  838.1m   3.9g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0    258      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 29:    2.5g 843.1m   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      3      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 30:    2.4g 927.7m   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      2      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 31:    3.3g   1.1g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 32:    1.9g   3.4g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 33:    2.3g 819.2m   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 34:    1.7g 721.5m   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 35:    3.5g   1.0g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 36:    3.6g   1.0g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 37:    1.8g 672.6m   0      0      0      0      0      0      0     12      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 38:  241.0m 965.4m   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 39:  254.4m   1.2g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 40:    3.5g   2.2g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      6      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 41:    3.4g   1.9g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 42:    3.4g   1.9g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 43:    1.4g   4.1g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 44:    1.4g   4.1g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 45:    2.5g   3.9g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 46:    2.5g   3.9g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 47:  128.2m   3.2g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 48:    1.0g   2.1g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 49:  251.5m   1.7g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 51:  910.2m 559.5m   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 52:  380.1m 708.0m   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 53:  568.2m   1.4g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      3      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 54:    3.7g   3.7g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      4      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 55:  776.9m   4.1g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 56:    1.5k   1.5k   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 57:    1.5k   1.5k   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 58:    1.5k   1.5k   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 59:    3.6g   3.7g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 60:    1.6g   1.6g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 61:    3.6g   3.7g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 62:  657.8m 517.0m   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 63:    3.6g   3.6g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 64:    3.6g   3.6g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 65:    3.6g   3.6g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 66:    3.6g   3.6g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 67:    4.0g   1.6g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      6      0      0      0      0      0      0      0    149      0
```

expected output for the above

```
          frames      enc    crc    crc    too    too    bad    enc   disc   link   loss   loss   frjt   fbsy  c3timeout    pcs    uncor
       tx     rx      in    err    g_eof  shrt   long   eof     out   c3    fail    sync   sig                  tx    rx     err    err
  2:  615.8m   1.8g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      2      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0   
  3:    2.1g   1.2g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      2      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0   
  4:    1.4g   2.9g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      6      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
  7:  512.5m  73.1m   0      0      0      0      0      0      0     17      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
  9:  599.8m   1.7g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      6      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 10:    2.8g 254.9m   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      6      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 12:    2.5g 556.1m   0      0      0      0      0      0      0    384      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 13:    2.9g   3.5g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      2      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 14:    1.7g   3.6g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0     12      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 16:  777.7m   3.1g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      6      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 23:    4.0g   2.9g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0     83      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 25:    1.2g   2.3g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      5      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 28:  838.1m   3.9g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0    258      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 29:    2.5g 843.1m   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      3      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 30:    2.4g 927.7m   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      2      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 37:    1.8g 672.6m   0      0      0      0      0      0      0     12      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 40:    3.5g   2.2g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      6      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 53:  568.2m   1.4g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      3      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 54:    3.7g   3.7g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      4      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 67:    4.0g   1.6g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      6      0      0      0      0      0      0      0    149      0
```

Comment: In an ideal world you'd be transforming this output to an array with headers. After that you can filter it. If you don't want to go that way, you can filter it with ```| ? {$_ -notlike "*0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0*"} ```

Comment: Or a bit shorter:   ```| ? {$_ -notlike "*$("   0   "*19)*"}```

Comment: Your command that get's you this output doesn't have any "output as CSV" switch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't know of any switches for porterrshow, but you can remove the lines with only zero values in the saved text file like below:

```
$result = switch -Regex -File 'D:\Test\PortErr.txt' {
    '^\s*\d+:(.+)$' { 
        $values = $matches[1] -replace '\s'
        if ($values -ne ('0' * $values.Length)) { $_ }
    }
    default { $_ }
}

# show on screen
$result

# write out to new file ?
$result | Set-Content -Path 'D:\Test\NewPortErr.txt'
```

Output using your example:

```
          frames      enc    crc    crc    too    too    bad    enc   disc   link   loss   loss   frjt   fbsy  c3timeout    pcs    uncor
       tx     rx      in    err    g_eof  shrt   long   eof     out   c3    fail    sync   sig                  tx    rx     err    err
  1:    2.5g   3.6g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      2      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0   
  3:    3.3g   1.5g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      3      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0
```

---

From your comment, I gather that the code needs to filter out lines with only zero values, **not counting** the first two columns `tx` and `rx`

For that, do:

```
$result = switch -Regex -File 'D:\Test\PortErr.txt' {
    '^\s*\d+:(.+)$' { 
        $values = ($matches[1].Trim() -split '\s+' | Select-Object -Skip 2) -join ''
        if ($values -ne ('0' * $values.Length)) { $_ }
    }
    default { $_ }
}

# show on screen
$result

# write out to new file ?
$result | Set-Content -Path 'D:\Test\NewPortErr.txt'
```

Using your new example, the output will be:

```
          frames      enc    crc    crc    too    too    bad    enc   disc   link   loss   loss   frjt   fbsy  c3timeout    pcs    uncor
       tx     rx      in    err    g_eof  shrt   long   eof     out   c3    fail    sync   sig                  tx    rx     err    err
  2:  615.8m   1.8g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      2      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0   
  3:    2.1g   1.2g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      2      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0   
  4:    1.4g   2.9g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      6      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
  7:  512.5m  73.1m   0      0      0      0      0      0      0     17      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
  9:  599.8m   1.7g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      6      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 10:    2.8g 254.9m   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      6      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 12:    2.5g 556.1m   0      0      0      0      0      0      0    384      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 13:    2.9g   3.5g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      2      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 14:    1.7g   3.6g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0     12      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 16:  777.7m   3.1g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      6      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 23:    4.0g   2.9g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0     83      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 25:    1.2g   2.3g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      5      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 28:  838.1m   3.9g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0    258      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 29:    2.5g 843.1m   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      3      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 30:    2.4g 927.7m   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      2      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 37:    1.8g 672.6m   0      0      0      0      0      0      0     12      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 40:    3.5g   2.2g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      6      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 53:  568.2m   1.4g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      3      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 54:    3.7g   3.7g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      4      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0   
 67:    4.0g   1.6g   0      0      0      0      0      0      0      6      0      0      0      0      0      0      0    149      0
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but still the result file contains rows with all zero's

Comment: @EmptyCoder Aha, your first example didn't show you meant `all zero` starting **after** the tx and rx columns.. I'll update my answer

Comment: @EmptyCoder Please see my edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot. you really a savior. Just one more thing, now after executing this script for all the switches, will have multiple files out of which for some data will be present and for some no data. How do I identify those files. Need to send mail with only those file which are having data.

Comment: @EmptyCoder You can do a line count on `$result` and if that is larger than 2 (skip the headers) then send the email  `if ($result.Count -gt 2) { <# send email #> }`. If you want to do this after the files have been writen, do almost the same `if (@(Get-Content -Path <thefile.txt>) -gt 2) { .. }`

Comment: @EmptyCoder Or, you can also decide to only write out the file if there are lines in it (not counting the headers): `if ($result.Count -gt 2) { $result | Set-Content -Path 'D:\Test\NewPortErr.txt' }`